# running sed passing a environment variable

Tags: shell, variables, sed, path

i have this sed command which works running from a shell

```
   /bin/sed -i -e '/^\['"9876"'\]/ r /etc/asterisk/tmp_'"9876"'.txt' /etc/asterisk/sip_peers.include
```

running it from a sh script it does not work:

```
#!/bin/bash

peers=/etc/asterisk/sip_peers.include
tmp=/etc/asterisk/tmp_$ext.txt

var=`cat < $tmp`
printenv > /etc/asterisk/zprintenv.txt
echo $tmp $ext > /etc/asterisk/zoutput.txt
/bin/sed -i -e '/^\['"$ext"'\]/ r /etc/asterisk/tmp_'"$ext"'.txt' /etc/asterisk/sip_peers.include
```

$ext is a environment variable and it is still present when i pass printenv to a text file. Also the $ext variable is passed to output.txt for testing purpose.

sip_peers.include, where the values from /etc/asterisk/tmp_$ext.txt will be inserted after []:

```
[9876]
qualify=yes
nat=yes
call-limit=4
....
```

output zoutput.txt:

```
/etc/asterisk/tmp_9876.txt 9876
```

snippet from zprintenv.txt:

```
contacts=1
vm=1
ext=9876
emergency_trunk=
callerid_override=
enduser_company_contacts=0
.....
```

output $tmp:

```
;mac=e02f6d613554
;model=spa504G
```

please take a look at it, i can not find the mistake since hours.
thanks a lot

Comment: What is the value of `ext` variable here?  it is not present here and can you share the input file you tried this on?

Comment: hi, i have updated my question.

Comment: this one is solved. it is a run time issue. the script is called from a gui and the file sip_peers.include is stored after the script is executed. so sed can not write to this file. thanks for help and sry for confusing

Answer (score 0):

Quoting OP comment:
It is a run time issue.
The script is called from a gui and the file sip_peers.include is stored **after** the script is executed. So sed cannot process the non-existing file.

(This seems like a use case that could be interesting for others. So I am making a Q/A pair by quoting answer from OPs comment,
matching a proposed edit to the title, for being found by users with similar problem.)